# Rails passing params to new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, parameters

I linked to a new-action giving a param in the URL. That param should be readable in the create-action so that i can put it in the new created object.

Specific: 
I'm on the show-page of a *bookshelf*. there is a link_to linked to the new-action of *book* with a paramter containing the id of the bookshelf. When creating the *book* i want to put the id of the *bookshelf* into the foreign key of the book (*bookshelf_id*).

How do i do this the rails way? 
The link_to looks like this: **link_to new_book_path(:bookshelf => bookshelf)**.
I tried reading and passing the param with **@book.bookshelf 
= Bookshelf.find(params[:bookshelf])** in the create-action but it was an empty string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Post the relationships. If you're on the bookshelf show page you have access to that instance of bookshelf

```
<%= link_to new_book_path(:bookshelf_id => params[:id]) %>
```

When you click that link your url should have ?bookshelf_id=123 (or whatever)

Then, to access that param from the new page, you can either do this in your form (assuming it's a conventional rails form):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :bookshelf_id, value: params['bookshelf_id'] %>
```

If you take this approach you don't have to do anything additional. Just pass the params as you normally would.

If you'd rather you can access this param in your controller:

```
bookshelf_id = params['bookshelf_id']
```

You can set it there and then add it to the object you're creating.

Comment: How to do this with simple form?

<%= hidden_field_tag :bookshelf_id, params[:bookshelf_id] %>